# Unexpected Matrix result in R

Tags: r, matrix

i'm new to R and this is my code:

```
f2 = function(n){
E = matrix(c(0),nrow = (n+1), ncol = (n+1));
k = -1;
for(j in 1:n+1){
 k = k + 1;
 l = 0;
 for(i in 1:n+1){
  if(k == 0){E[i,j] = 1;}
  if(k == 1){E[i,j] = 1 - (2*l)/n;}

  l = l + 1;
 }
}
print(E);

}
```

this has this "unexpected" result when printing for n = 2:

```
> f2(2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    1
[3,]    0    1    0
```

but i want to print this:

```
> f2(2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1   0
[2,]    1    0   0
[3,]    1   -1   0
```

and i think my logic is right because i tried in Java too
and i had the expected result, so i don't know what's wrong here.
And unfortunately that's the start of a bigger program that i want to
complete so it is really annoyning, also if you can show me a better way
of creating and manipulating matrices in R it would be very helpful.

Comment: Replace `1:n+1` with `1:(n+1)`.

Comment: parenthesis are your friend, look: :)

Comment: Welcome to R! Feel free to leave those semicolons at the door :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a visual aide to the comments above:

```
> 1:5+1
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

> 1:(5+1)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
```

Comment: thanks, sometimes i swear i must be blind in front the screen, i need some sleep too :).

Answer (score 4):

...but more generally, you will eventually become very unhappy with this style of R code. It's good to use your knowledge of other languages (Java?) to get started, but if you write R code like Java, you will really, really hate R.

This does the exact same thing in a much more R way:

```
> k <- matrix(0:2,3,3,byrow = TRUE)
> l <- matrix(0:2,3,3)
> ifelse(k == 0,1,ifelse(k == 1,1 - (2*l)/2,0))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    1   -1    0
```

Comment: Yes, i begin to see that, fortunately it will be one of my last projects, because it's really painful right now to start using and get used to another style.

Comment: +1 for the cleanup.  But nested `ifelse` statements might get a bit confusing if someone is unfamiliar with `R`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I agree. I offered this up as a sort of "next step" to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Following @joran, a generalization for arbitrary `n`:

```
f3 <- function(n)
{
    E <- matrix(0, nrow = (n+1), ncol = (n+1))
    E[,1] <- 1
    E[,2] <- seq(from=1, to=-1, length.out=n+1)
    E
}
```

To show the power of vectorization:

```
> system.time(M <- f2(5000))
   user  system elapsed 
  41.37    0.20   41.78 
> system.time(N <- f3(5000))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.07    0.11    0.19
```

(after fixing f2 with parenthesis and removing `print`)